# How to reload native stack page after come back on another screen

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log('inside component'); 
    this.loadUsernameFromSharedStorage();
  }

  componentDidUpdate = async () => {
    console.log('inside componentdidupdate');
    this.loadUsernameFromSharedStorage(); 
  }
```

This my MainPage.js code where i am trying to load data. when i am launch App then MainPage.js is load first after that i am navigate to SecondPage.js where i insert some values and click on save button to save those values in phone storage using react-native-shared-group-perference and navigate to MainPage again. but when i am back to MainPage.js then didn't get updated values on the MainPage.js.

Comment: you can use `redux`

Comment: Is there any other way to do it rather than redux ?

Comment: you can use `AsyncStorage` but it's deprecated, this [link](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-react-native-localstorage-libraries) might be helpful